# What are the rules for resuming/scoring a rain shortened game in baseball?

Tags: baseball, mlb

There are three possibilities that I can see.

The first is if less than half of a baseball game (four and a half innings) is played, then the game is canceled and a completely new make up game is scheduled. That, I can follow.

My understanding is that if the home team is leading when the game is interrupted during the bottom of the fifth or later, the rest of the game isn't played, and the home team gets the win.

There was one instance I remember, when the rain interrupted the Yankees, who were leading 2-1 in the top of the 8th . There was a partial "makeup" on a subsequent day, not of the whole game, but of the remainder of the eighth and ninth innings.

Then there's the case of the Pirates at Atlanta tonight, with the visitors leading 3-2 at the end of six. I read that unless the game were continued the same night, a victory would be recorded for the Pirates over the six inning game.

If the home team is leading after four and a half, determination of the win seems trivial. But if the visiting team is leading, how would they determine whether the game will be scored as a visitors' win or continued later from the point of interruption?

Answer (score 1):

In the MLB today, when a game is cancelled (usually from rain), it is either scheduled to be completed on a specific date, or cut short to however many innings were played. They announce when and where exactly it will be made up with the announcement it is postponed. Early in the season, games are always finished, wither on an off day, or by creating a double header, where only part of the first game is played. Later in the season, if no suitable date can be found to finish the game, the game is called. If it is at the end of an inning, or half inning when the home team is ahead, the game will be cut short, and the leading team would get the win.

To answer your question, If it is in the middle of an inning and the visitors are ahead, they will either not call a weather suspension and finish the inning or use the score at the end of the previously completed inning. See [Rules Of Baseball](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf) 7.02(b) part 4, (page 88).

This can lead to some interesting situation, such as last fall, when the [Cubs-Pirates game ended in a Tie](http://m.mlb.com/news/article/204121484/cubs-pirates-game-suspended-ends-in-tie/). This was only done because the game would not affect either teams chances at making the playoffs.

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong but I don't think a game is cut short unless it qualifies as an official game (6 innings I think). For example, if a rainout occurs after two innings the game will not be awarded to team leading at that time.

I thought these sites were suppose to informative and fun? The other sites I'm in are...

Comment: I believe the rule is five innings, not six (four and a half if the home team is winning, just like there's no bottom of the ninth.)

Comment: Hedging your answer is pointless. Either you know it is that number, or there is no way to be sure, or you don't know either way at all. The first should be referenced, the second should be justified or referenced, and the latter should be left out entirely.